# Opengles glViewport parameters

Tags: android, opengl-es

According to the documentation [here](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml%5D%5B1%5D), the first two parameters of this function (found in every hello Triangle example for Android)

```
GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
```

stand for the lower left of the screen. How is it possible? Souldn't Gl coordinates have there -1,-1?

Comment: glViewport map pixels to screen coord, pixels that have been previously transformed by the projection matrix that covert gl coordinates to pixels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of `glViewport` is to establish a relation between OpenGL NDC coordinates (that are coordinates after the whole coordinate transformation pipeline has been passed) and a rectangle in *pixel coordinates* in the target framebuffer.

Comment: I understand that glViewport maps NCD to pixel frame buffer. Does that mean that in the frame buffer 0,0 are the coordinates of the lower left portion of the display?

Comment: @Muteking: Yes, OpenGL puts the pixel origin of the framebuffer into the lower left. If you think about it, negative numbers make no sense for the framebuffer. The framebuffer is just a large hunk of memory indexed by positive valued pixel coordinates.